# Dijkstr não encontra menor caminho

Tags: c++, path

Estou implementando o algoritmo de dijkstra para encontrar o menor caminho em uma rede. Começando de um nó de origem s, preciso calcular o menor caminho para chegar em todos os outros nós que existem na rede. Mas o algoritmo não está funcionando corretamente.

Aqui está o código? (HEU é uma struct de grafo)

```
int dijkstra(GRAPHD &HEU, int s) {
HEU.d[s] = 0; 
for (int i = 1; i <= HEU.nb_nodes; i++) {
    if (i != s)
        HEU.d[i] = INT_MAX; 
}
for (int i = 1; i <= HEU.nb_nodes; i++) {
    HEU.S[i] = 0; 
    HEU.Q[i] = i; 
}

while (!vazio(HEU)) {
    int u = extract_mimimum(HEU);
    HEU.S[u] = 1;
    retira(HEU, u);
    for (int i = 1; i <= HEU.nb_nodes; i++) {
        if (HEU.qr[u][i] != -1) { //indica que existe o arco
            if (HEU.qr[u][i] != -2) { //indica que existe o arco
                if (HEU.d[HEU.qr[u][i]] > HEU.d[u] + HEU.c[u][HEU.qr[u][i]])
                    HEU.d[HEU.qr[u][i]] = HEU.d[u] + HEU.c[u][HEU.qr[u][i]];
            }
        }
    }
}


return HEU.d;
}
```

O problema é quando começa do nó 2. 
Todas as distâncias na matriz HEU.c[ ] [ ] são 1 e o grafo é assim:

```
HEU.qr[1][1] = 5;

HEU.qr[2][1] = 1;

HEU.qr[2][2] = 3;

HEU.qr[3][1] = 7;

HEU.qr[3][2] = 4;

HEU.qr[4][1] = 8;

HEU.qr[5][1] = 9;

HEU.qr[6][1] = 2;

HEU.qr[6][2] = 5;

HEU.qr[7][1] = 11;

HEU.qr[7][2] = 6;

HEU.qr[8][1] = 7;

HEU.qr[9][1] = 10;

HEU.qr[10][1] = 6;

HEU.qr[10][2] = 11;

HEU.qr[11][1] = 15;

HEU.qr[12][1] = 8;

HEU.qr[13][1] = 9;

HEU.qr[14][1] = 10;

HEU.qr[14][2] = 13;

HEU.qr[15][1] = 14;

HEU.qr[15][2] = 16;

HEU.qr[16][1] = 12;
```

Por exemplo, HEU.qr[16][1] = 12 significa que o nó 16 tem somente um vizinho e é o 12. Então, HEU.qr[15][1] = 14 e HEU.qr[15][2] = 16 significa que o nó 15 tem dois vizinhos que são 14 e 16.

As funções auxiliares são essas:

```
int vazio(GRAPHD &HEU) {
for (int i = 1; i <= HEU.nb_nodes; i++) {
    if (HEU.Q[i] != 0)
        return 0;
}
return 1;
}

int extract_mimimum(GRAPHD &HEU) {
int min = INT_MAX;
for (int i = 1; i <= HEU.nb_nodes; i++) {
    if (HEU.Q[i] != 0) {
        if (HEU.d[i] < min) {
            min = i;                
        }
    }
}
return min;
}

void retira(GRAPHD &HEU, int a) {
for (int i = 1; i <= HEU.nb_nodes; i++) {
    if (HEU.Q[i] == a) HEU.Q[i] = 0;
}
 }
```

O vetor de distâncias começando pelo nó 2 deveria ser 1 0 1 2 2 3 2 3 3 4 3 6 6 5 4 5 mas está sendo 1 0 1 2 2 3 2 3 3 4 3 8 8 7 6 7. 
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Inclua a definição da estrutura GRAPHD.